# Trailcams and disabling them

Tags: email

I'm using trailcams (10) for security in my yard. I'm dealing with vandals destroying my trees and set up trailcams to catch the person. For almost 3 months they have been cutting my trees but somehow getting by all 10 of my cameras. They show me checking on the trees then hours later the next frame will be the trees damaged. Nothing inbetween. How is it possible that they can damage my trees But not be on the cameras? 
Frustrated gardener over here

Comment: Are you sure that your cameras are recording a video and not taking a snapshot every, say, 5 minutes?

Comment: @forest Trailcams normally take pictures whenever they detect motion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about __information__ security. I doubt that trees count as information and there are no details here which suggest some sort of hacking the cameras to bypass their task.

Comment: If they know where the trailcams are they could simply be blocking or switching them off. Set the trailcams to cover each other. Even if they pull and selectively erase the memory cards, it's pretty difficult to syncronize that with another cam.

Comment: The cameras are set to take 3 pics in a row when motion is detected. They capture birds, critters and smoke from my firepit sets them off. Can't understand how someone can get by all 10 to continually cut branches off my ornamental trees.

Comment: The cameras do face each other as well as the trees being targeted. My property is over an acre so at least 1 cam should pick up someone messing with them. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It sounds like, in this case, the information being protected is data on the cameras. We have questions about generic locks and lock picking despite the fact that locks protect physical items. Though I think this question might be too broad as it stands, in any case.

Comment: @forest: to cite myself: *"...and there are __no details here which suggest some sort of hacking the cameras to bypass their task__."*. Thus, if it is about protecting the trees it would be off-topic. If it is about protecting the photos it would be too sparse on actual information, i.e. everything would just be unfounded speculation (i.e. too broad).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'd think techniques to bypass cameras, even if they don't involve "hacking" in the traditional sense, could still be considered hacking. Exploiting motion-detection behavior by slowly saturating the photosensor with infrared light is a threat that fits in with information security (not that I think OP's vandals are using that technique...). The question would be no different if OP never mentioned trees. And yes, I do think it is too broad, rather than off-topic due to being about trees (which I doubt). I'll mark it as too broad myself if OP doesn't add more information soon.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very difficult to bypass a motion-sensitive cameras unless the attacker is dedicated and at least moderately knowledgeable. Some motion-activated cameras simply use fuzzy comparison of a frame with a few previous frames, and initiate recording if the sum of differences reaches a certain threshold. Very slowly placing a lens cover or other obstruction in front of the camera could blind it, and it would not begin recording because the movements are too gradual for it to count them as motion. The obstruction could then be slowly removed afterwards. The same could be accomplished by using a slowly-intensifying light source (even one not in the visible spectrum) to saturate its sensors. Depending on exactly how it detects motion, this could take anywhere from minutes to hours.

Other motion-sensitive cameras use more traditional motion detection, for example with microwaves (this is how automatic doors detect motion) or infrared lasers.  In those cases, certain materials are "invisible" to the camera due to the way they reflect radiation. This is more likely to be used if you are protecting something of extremely high value against a very sophisticated organization. It's quite unlikely that a vandal who has something against your trees will be using those techniques.

Finally, if they are IP cameras that are insecurely configured or connected to a network, any recording made by them could be paused or altered by a hacker. While this is not particularly difficult as most IP cameras are remarkably insecure, it's still not a likely attack vector in your case. To make it more difficult anyway, you should ensure that the cameras are not exposed to the outside internet, that their firmware is up-to-date, and that they are not using default admin credentials.

### The real solution

So what should you do? The answer is actually pretty obvious. Set your cameras to record 24/7 rather than when motion is detected. You will need a larger storage medium or you will need to reduce video quality or framerate, but it will defeat all but the most sophisticated attackers. This will protect from any evasion of the flimsy motion-detection features in most cameras.